# Cannot find non-www version of newly created subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, web-hosting, subdomain

Using Cpanel, I've just created a subdomain: **members.domain.com**. I can view the domain on **www**.members.domain.com but the non-www version doesn't exist. Pinging it I get 'could not find host'.

I've been in the DNS settings and even tried making a new A record for the non-www version, but no luck.

Is it simply a case of waiting for it to propagate, or is there something else I can do. Obviously I can't redirect using a .htaccess if the domain isn't being found.

Thanks.

Comment: Since I'm guessing your domain isn't actually `domain.com`, it's hard to check for you.

Comment: What's output from `dig members.domain.com`?

Comment: ceejayoz, its members dot hbsaonline dot com, and Shane I'm not familiar with the Dig command :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://members.hbsaonline.com/ is resolving for me at 173.193.148.93.  It looks like you just need to allow DNS propagation time.